# log4j2 to elastic search configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, log4j2, elastic-stack

I am trying to configure log4j2 to elasticsearch and got the next problem:

> ERROR No Elasticsearch client factory
>   [JestHttp|ElasticsearchBulkProcessor] provided for AsyncBatchDelivery:
>   clientObjectFactory

But I have property JestHttp set up, so, it should work as clientObjectFactory to my understanding.

Any ideas?

my config file looks like that:

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Elasticsearch name="elasticsearchAsyncBatch">
            <RollingIndexName indexName="log4j2" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
            <AsyncBatchDelivery>
                <JestHttp serverUris="myhost:9200" />
            </AsyncBatchDelivery>
        </Elasticsearch>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="MyLogger" level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="elasticsearchAsyncBatch" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I needed not only log4j2-elasticsearch-core dependency, but log4j2-elasticsearch-jest as well.

So, just added the next code to pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.appenders.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2-elasticsearch-jest</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the owner of this plugin. You need **only one** of the following:

- log4j2-elasticsearch-jest
- log4j2-elasticsearch-hc
- log4j2-elasticsearch(x)-bulkprocessor

log4j2-elasticsearch-core is a compile dependency of each one of them, so it will get there anyway. It has to be specified only if you write your own extensions of core classses.